# Highcharts not rendering after post ajax request

Tags: sql-server, ajax, highcharts, asp-classic

I have 2 asp pages, in the first one I have a form that I inform a parameter using AJAX and send it to the second asp page that connect to a MSSQL database, run a query using a date parameter came from the first ASP page and return the Query result to ASP Variables and then populates Highcharts.

Graphics works fine passing variables throght querystrings, but Using AJAX the graphics wont draw,no error, simples returns a blank graphic.

TESTE.ASP

```html
<!--#include virtual ="/BI/header.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual ="/BI/sidebar.asp"-->
<%
%>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<script>
function OnCheckAvailability()
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
oRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

oRequest.open("POST", "vendas.asp", true);
oRequest.onreadystatechange = UpdateCheckAvailability;

oRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
oRequest.send("strCmd=availability&strData1=" + document.form1.data1.value);
}

function UpdateCheckAvailability()
{
document.getElementById("Available").innerHTML = oRequest.responseText;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<div>
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="form1">

<label for="newuserid">Data:</label>

<input type="text" name="data1" id="data1 size="20" />

<input id="btnCheckAvailability" type="button" value="Check Availability" onClick="OnCheckAvailability();"><br>

<div id="Available"></div>

</form>
```

VENDAS.ASP

```html
<!--#include virtual ="/BI/LIB/lib.asp"-->

<%

' Form Variables
dim strCmd
dim strdata1

strCmd = trim(Request.Form("strCmd").Item)
strdata1 = trim(Request.Form("strdata1").Item)

'nLimFor  = Request.QueryString("fornec")
'nLimProd = Request.QueryString("produto")
Dim nLimFor
Dim nLimProd

Dim DATA1
Dim cEmpr
Dim cEmprOld
Dim cFil
Dim cFilialF
Dim cFilialP
Dim cFornP
Dim strQryL
Dim strQryF
Dim strQryP
Dim strTot
Dim strPT
Dim nCont

'Conexão com o Banco de Dados
 ' Criar objeto de conexão com a base de dados e executar a Query na tabela SM0
 Set rsVendEF = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  rsVendEF.Open qryEmpFil, strConn

'Seta as variaveis
nLimFor  = 15
nLimProd = 15
'DATA1    = strdata1
DATA1 = Dia()
nCont    = 0
cEmpr    = rsVendEF.Fields("M0_CODIGO")
cFil     = rsVendEF.Fields("M0_CODFIL")
cEmprOld = ""
cFornP   = ""

'Query das lojas
strQryL = " DECLARE "&_
   " @DATA VARCHAR(8) = '"&DATA1&"' "&_
   " SELECT FILIAL, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM( "&_
   " SELECT ISNULL(L2_FILIAL,'') FILIAL, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VRUNIT),0) PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
   " WHERE L2_EMISSAO = @DATA "&_
   " GROUP BY L2_FILIAL WITH CUBE "

'Query de fornecedores
strQryF = " DECLARE "&_
   " @DATA VARCHAR(8) = "&DATA1&", "&_
   " @ROWS INT        = "&nLimFor&" "&_
   "SELECT  RANK, FILIAL, NOMEFOR, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   "FROM "&_
   "( "&_
   " SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FILIAL ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR) AS RANK, "&_
   "   FILIAL, NOMEFOR, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM( "&_
   "   SELECT  L2_FILIAL FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ NOMEFOR, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
   "   FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
   "   INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON B1_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SB1",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "   INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON A2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SA2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND A2_COD = B1_PROC AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "   WHERE  L2_EMISSAO = @DATA AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "   GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ "&_
   "  ) TAB11 "

'Query de Produtos
strQryP = " DECLARE "&_
   " @DATA VARCHAR(8) = '"&DATA1&"', "&_
   " @ROWS INT        = "&nLimProd&" "&_
   " SELECT RANK, FILIAL, NOMEFOR, NOMEPROD, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM "&_
   " ( "&_
   " SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NOMEFOR ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR, NOMEPROD) AS RANK, "&_
   "  FILIAL, NOMEFOR, NOMEPROD, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM "&_
   " ( "&_
   " SELECT  ISNULL(L2_FILIAL,'') FILIAL, ISNULL(A2_NREDUZ,'') NOMEFOR, ISNULL(B1_DESC,'') NOMEPROD, "&_
   "    ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
   " FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
   " INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON "&_
   "    B1_FILIAL = ''  AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1'  AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   " INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON "&_
   "    A2_FILIAL = ''  AND A2_COD = B1_PROC  AND A2_NREDUZ IN "&_
   "    ( SELECT  NOMEFOR "&_
   "     FROM( "&_
   "      SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FILIAL ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR) AS RANK, "&_
   "        FILIAL, NOMEFOR, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
   "      FROM( "&_
   "       SELECT L2_FILIAL FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ NOMEFOR, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
   "       FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
   "       INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON B1_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SB1",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "       INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON A2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SA2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND A2_COD = B1_PROC AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "       WHERE  L2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SL2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND L2_EMISSAO = @DATA AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   "       GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ "&_
   "       ) TAB11 "&_
   "      )TAB21 "&_
   "     WHERE  TAB21.RANK <= @ROWS "&_
   "     ORDER BY FILIAL, PRODVAL DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWS ROWS ONLY "&_
   "    ) "&_
   "    AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   " WHERE  L2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SL2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND L2_EMISSAO = @DATA  AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
   " GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ, B1_DESC, L2_VLRITEM "&_
   " ) A "

cEmprOld = cEmpr
rsVendEF.MoveNext
DO WHILE NOT rsVendEF.eof
 cEmpr = rsVendEF.Fields("M0_CODIGO")
 cFil  = rsVendEF.Fields("M0_CODFIL")
 'nCont = nCont + 1

 If cEmprOld <> cEmpr Then
  cEmprOld = cEmpr

  'Query das lojas Continuação
  strQryL = strQryL + " UNION ALL "&_
     " SELECT ISNULL(L2_FILIAL,'') FILIAL, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VRUNIT),0) PRODVAL "&_
     " FROM "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
     " WHERE L2_EMISSAO = @DATA "&_
     " GROUP BY L2_FILIAL WITH CUBE "

  'Query de fornecedores Continuação
  strQryF = strQryF + " UNION ALL "&_
     " SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FILIAL ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR) AS RANK, "&_
     "   FILIAL, NOMEFOR, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
     " FROM( "&_
     "   SELECT  L2_FILIAL FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ NOMEFOR, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
     "   FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
     "   INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON B1_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SB1",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
     "   INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON A2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SA2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND A2_COD = B1_PROC AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
     "   WHERE  L2_EMISSAO = @DATA AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
     "   GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ "&_
     "  ) TAB12 "
 End If

 'Query de produtos Continuação
 strQryP = strQryP + " UNION ALL "&_
 " SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NOMEFOR ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR, NOMEPROD) AS RANK, "&_
 "  FILIAL, NOMEFOR, NOMEPROD, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
 " FROM "&_
 " ( "&_
 " SELECT  ISNULL(L2_FILIAL,'') FILIAL, ISNULL(A2_NREDUZ,'') NOMEFOR, ISNULL(B1_DESC,'') NOMEPROD, "&_
 "    ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
 " FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
 " INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON "&_
 "    B1_FILIAL = ''  AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1'  AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 " INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON "&_
 "    A2_FILIAL = ''  AND A2_COD = B1_PROC  AND A2_NREDUZ IN "&_
 "    ( SELECT  NOMEFOR "&_
 "     FROM( "&_
 "      SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY FILIAL ORDER BY PRODVAL DESC, FILIAL, NOMEFOR) AS RANK, "&_
 "        FILIAL, NOMEFOR, QUANT, PRODVAL "&_
 "      FROM( "&_
 "        SELECT  L2_FILIAL FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ NOMEFOR, ISNULL(SUM(L2_QUANT),0) QUANT, ISNULL(SUM(L2_VLRITEM),0) PRODVAL "&_
 "        FROM  "&xGEmpr("SL2", cEmpr)&" SL2 "&_
 "        INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SB1", cEmpr)&" SB1 ON B1_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SB1",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND B1_COD = L2_PRODUTO AND B1_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 "        INNER JOIN "&xGEmpr("SA2", cEmpr)&" SA2 ON A2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SA2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND A2_COD = B1_PROC AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 "        WHERE  L2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SL2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND L2_EMISSAO = @DATA AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 "        GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ "&_
 "       ) TAB11 "&_
 "      )TAB21 "&_
 "     WHERE  TAB21.RANK <= @ROWS "&_
 "     ORDER BY FILIAL, PRODVAL DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWS ROWS ONLY "&_
 "    ) "&_
 "    AND A2_MSBLQL <> '1' AND SA2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 " WHERE  L2_FILIAL = '"&xFilial("SL2",cEmpr,cFil)&"' AND L2_EMISSAO = @DATA  AND SL2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "&_
 " GROUP BY L2_FILIAL, A2_NREDUZ, B1_DESC, L2_VLRITEM "&_
 " ) A "

 rsVendEF.MoveNext
Loop

'Query de lojas finalizando
strQryL = strQryL + " ) L "&_
     " ORDER BY FILIAL ;"

'Query de fornecedores finalizando
strQryF = strQryF + " ) TAB21 "&_
     " WHERE  TAB21.RANK <= @ROWS "&_
     " ORDER BY FILIAL, PRODVAL DESC ;"

'Query de produtos finalizando
strQryP = strQryP + ") B "&_
     "WHERE B.RANK <= @ROWS "&_
     "ORDER BY "&_
     "  FILIAL, NOMEFOR, PRODVAL DESC-- OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWS ROWS ONLY ;"

'Criando um objeto de conexão com a base de dados e executamos a Query
set rsQryL=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsQryL.Open strQryL, strConexao

set rsQryF=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsQryF.Open strQryF, strConexao

set rsQryP=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsQryP.Open strQryP, strConexao

'TOTALIZADORES
DO WHILE NOT rsQryL.eof
 If rsQryL.FIELDS("FILIAL") <> "" Then
  Exit Do
 End If
 strTot = strTot + cdbl(rsQryL.FIELDS("PRODVAL"))
 strPT  = strPT  + cdbl(rsQryL.FIELDS("QUANT"))
' strT   =  100 'strT   + cdbl(rsQry.FIELDS("CLIENTES"))
' strTKT =  100 'strTKT + cdbl(rsQry.FIELDS("TICKET"))

 rsQryL.MoveNext
Loop
'strTKT = strTKT / nCont

%>


<!-- Trecho HTML do Fonte-->
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   ${demo.css}
    
        </style>

<!-- Continuação do Trecho HighCharts do Fonte-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(
 function ()
 {
  //create a variable so we can pass the value dynamically
  var chartype = 'column';
  
  //On page load call the function setDynamicChart
  setDynamicChart(chartype);
  
  //jQuery part a- On Click call the function setDynamicChart(dynval) and pass the chart type
  $('.option').click(function(){
  //get the value from 'a' tag
  
  var chartype = $(this).attr('id');
  setDynamicChart(chartype);
 });

  function setDynamicChart(chartype){

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts
  (
   {

    chart:   { type: chartype
         
       },
    exporting: { enabled: true  },
    navigation: { menuItemStyle:   { fontWeight: 'normal', background: 'none' },
        buttonOptions:   { align: 'left' },
        menuItemHoverStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', background: 'none', color: 'black' }
       },

    title:  { text: 'Vendas no Dia' },
    subtitle: { text: 'Clique para detalhes.' },
    xAxis:  { type: 'category' },
    yAxis:  { title: { text: 'Valor total por loja em R$' } },
    legend:  { enabled: false },
    plotOptions:{ series: { borderWidth: 0, dataLabels: { enabled: true, format: '{point.y:.2f}' } } },

    tooltip: { headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
         pointFormat:  '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>R$ {point.y:.2f}}</b><br/>'
       },

    series:  [{
        name: "Lojas",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data:
        [<% DO WHILE NOT rsQryL.eof %>
         <%If rsQryL.Fields("FILIAL") <> "" Then%>
         {
          name:  "Filial: <%=rsQryL.Fields("FILIAL")%>",
          y:   <%Response.Write( REPLACE(rsQryL.Fields("PRODVAL"),",",".") )%> ,
          drilldown: "Detalhes F<%=rsQryL.Fields("FILIAL")%>"
         },
         <% End If %>
         <% rsQryL.MoveNext %>
        <% Loop %>
        ]
       }],

    drilldown: { series:
        [<% DO WHILE NOT rsQryF.eof %>
          { name: "Detalhes F<%=rsQryF.Fields("FILIAL")%>",
           colorByPoint: true,
           id:  "Detalhes F<%=rsQryF.Fields("FILIAL")%>",
           data:
           [
           <%  cFilialF = rsQryF.Fields("FILIAL") %>
           <% DO WHILE NOT rsQryF.eof
            If rsQryF.Fields("FILIAL") <> cFilialF Then
             Exit Do
            End If%>
             {
              name:   "<%=rsQryF.Fields("NOMEFOR")%>",
              y:    <%Response.Write( REPLACE(rsQryF.Fields("PRODVAL"),",",".") )%>,
              drilldown: "F_<%=(rsQryF.Fields("FILIAL")&rsQryF.Fields("NOMEFOR"))%>"
             },
             <% rsQryF.MoveNext %>
            <%Loop %>
           ]
          },

          <%
          If NOT rsQryP.eof Then
           cFilialP = rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL")
          End If %>
          <% DO WHILE NOT rsQryP.eof
           If rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL") <> cFilialP Then
            Exit Do
           End If%>
           {
            name: "F_<%=(rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL") & rsQryP.Fields("NOMEFOR") )%>",
            id:  "F_<%=(rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL") & rsQryP.Fields("NOMEFOR") )%>",
            data:
            [
             <%cFornP = rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL") & rsQryP.Fields("NOMEFOR")
             DO WHILE NOT rsQryP.eof
             If rsQryP.Fields("FILIAL") & rsQryP.Fields("NOMEFOR") <> cFornP Then
              Exit Do
             End If%>
              {
               name:   "<%=rsQryP.Fields("NOMEPROD")%>",
               y:    <%Response.Write( REPLACE(rsQryP.Fields("PRODVAL"),",",".") )%>
              },
              <% rsQryP.MoveNext
             Loop %>
            ]
           },
          <%Loop
         Loop%>
        ]
       }

   });
  }   
 });
 <%
  ' Fecha os Record Set's
  rsVendEF.Close
  rsQryL.Close
  rsQryF.Close
  rsQryP.Close
 %>

</script>
<!-- Fim do Trecho HighCharts do Fonte-->

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main"><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <h1 class="page-header"><!--/.row-->
  </h1>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-blue panel-widget ">
     <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
       <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon-l"></em>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
       <div class="small">Venda Total</div>
       <div class="small"><% response.Write(FormatCurrency(strTot))%></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-orange panel-widget">
     <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
       <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment glyphicon-l"></em>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
       <div class="small">Itens Vendidos</div>
       <div class="small"><%response.Write(strPT)%></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-teal panel-widget">
     <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
       <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-l"></em>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
       <div class="small">Clientes</div>
       <div class="small"><%response.Write(strT)%></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-red panel-widget">
     <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
       <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats glyphicon-l"></em>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
       <div class="small">TICKET MED.</div>
       <div class="small"><%response.Write(FormatCurrency(strTkt))%></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--/.row-->
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Vendas do Dia</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
                     
<div align="right" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height: 15px;">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option" id="column">Colunas - </a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option" id="bar">Barras - </a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option" id="line">Linhas - </a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option" id="pie">Pizza</a>
</div>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
<!-- Fim do Trecho HTML do Fonte-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the code is not triggering the `setDynamicChart` function. In the current code, it is called on load of the page, but during an ajax load, it is not happening. You will have to call the function after the ajax load is complete.

As you are already using JQuery, I have changed your code to do an ajax call the JQuery way:

```
<!--#include virtual ="/BI/header.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual ="/BI/sidebar.asp"-->
<%
'your asp code as is..
%>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<div>
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="form1">

<label for="newuserid">Data:</label>

<input type="text" name="data1" id="data1 size="20" />

<input id="btnCheckAvailability" type="button" value="Check Availability"><br>

<div id="Available">
<script>
function drawGraph()
{
    var chartype='column';
    setDynamicChart(chartype);
}

$("#btnCheckAvailability").on("click",function(){

        $.post("vendas.asp",{"strCmd":"availability","strData1":$("#data1").val()},
        function(data)
        {
            if(data)
            {
                $("#Available").html(data);
                drawGraph();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("no data");
            }

        });
});

</script>
</div>  
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the called page, you can remove the script includes.

This works for me with some dummy values, since i don't have the db setup. You will have to make some changes at your end.